# Which of the two methods I am mentioning here is correct for calculating the Mode of a grouped data?

Tags: statistics, median

The question is as follows: -

[Question for calculation of Mean, Median and Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF2YT.png)

Direct calculation of mode:-

[Direct calculation of mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTQb5.png)

Calculation of mode using mean and median and the relation between mean, median and mode:-

[Calculation of mode through other method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX7nG.png)

I am getting two different answers through two methods as shown in the pictures attached above. Which one is correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Please don't downvote my question. I have attached screenshots of website and book but I do have solved this question myself and am really confused that which is correct. I think the empirical formula Mode = 3Median - 2Mean is not always correct but I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: Dear Jose, I shall try. Actually I am new to this forum so have to learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Finding a mode of data can be difficult, especially if it's grouped data. The choice of group boundaries can make a big difference in the answer you get. As a practicing statistician, I have to say
the problems about finding modes of small samples from grouped data are far more prevalent in elementary statistics classes taught by
mathematicians than in real-life applications.

The first thing you need to look for in order to make sense
of finding the mode for data is the definition. Can there be only one mode according to the definition or can there be several modes? (Sometimes one speaks of 'multi-modal' samples.)

Especially when sample sizes are small, the mode of grouped data, or data in a histogram, can depend greatly on what group boundaries are chosen.

While you are a student in a beginning statistics class, you need focus on the textbook definition of sample mode, and figure out how to use the
formulas in your text or class notes. Getting alternative
definitions and formulas from various sources is not the most
direct route to success in the class or to understanding
statistical principles. If you do serious applied statistics
later on, then there may be better methods for you to use.

**Small samples.** Consider the following sample of size $n = 30$ from a normal distribution with mean $\mu=100$ and standard deviation $\sigma=15.$ Some numerical descriptive statistics made
directly from the data are shown below.

```
set.seed(430)
x = rnorm(30, 100, 15)
summary(x); length(x); sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  81.28   90.82   98.05  101.37  113.11  135.43 
[1] 30          # sample size
[1] 13.88452    # sample standard deviation
```

Below we have two histograms. These are *density*
histograms because the widths and heights are scaled so that
the total area of all the bars in a histogram sums to $1.$
Tick marks on the horizontal axis show the exact values of the thirty observations. The orange curves show the normal population density curve.

At left the modal interval is $(90,100].$ The usual formulas
for getting the mode from grouped data would put "the mode'
somewhere inside that interval. Some texts might say a second
(or minor) modal interval is $(110,120).$ If the purpose
of the sample mode is to estimate the mode of the distribution,
then neither one will give a very good estimate; the mode of
a of the normal distribution is at $100.$

At left is a histogram with one, two, or three modal intervals--depending on which book you read. Formulas might put 'the mode' at about 95.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2");  rug(x)
 curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
hist(x, prob=T, br=15, col="skyblue2"); rug(x)
 curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

The histograms is the figures below are the same as above.
Here the curves are 'kernel density estimators' (CDEs) based on
the data. CDEs attempt to guess what the population density
curve might look like. With only thirty observations KDEs
typically aren't very good. Here they would estimate the
population mode at about 92.

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2");  rug(x)
 lines(density(x), col="maroon", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
hist(x, prob=T, br=15, col="skyblue2"); rug(x)
 lines(density(x), col="maroon", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

**Larger samples.** By contrast, with $n = 300$ observations instead of $30$
we have enough data to make sense of the concept of the mode
of a sample. There is one modal interval, and formulas based
on a histogram will estimate the mode at a little above $100.$
Also, the KDE estimates the population mode almost exactly
at $100$ (even if $n=300$ isn't a large enough sample size
for KDEs to have a nice normal shape).

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  59.49   88.55   99.51   99.14  108.33  140.00 
[1] 300
[1] 15.56456
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
  lines(density(x), col="maroon", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
hist(x, prob=T, br=15, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
  lines(density(x), col="maroon", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

**Large sample.** With $n = 3000$ there is little
doubt about the sample mode. It is a good estimate
of the population mode (the point where the density
function achieves its maximum).

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(3000, 100, 15)
summary(x); length(x); sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  49.06   90.02  100.18  100.08  110.05  147.94 
[1] 3000
[1] 14.95474
```

[image]

*Note:* In R, a KDE has 512 $(x,y)$ components. One can
find the mode of the KDE as follows:

```
X = density(x)$x
Y = density(x)$y
mean(X[Y==max(Y)])
[1] 100.4143
```